# why does join-path not let you join a arbitrary drive letter to a -childpath value?

Tags: powershell

```
join-path -path 'q:' -ChildPath '\Users\ralf\Documents\document.pdf'
```

or

```
join-path -path 'q:' -ChildPath (split-path -path 'c:\Users\ralf\Documents\document.pdf' -NoQualifier)
```

The above two examples, fail with an error `Join-Path: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'q' does not exist.`, the following works as expected:

```
join-path -path 'c:' -ChildPath '\Users\ralf\Documents\document.pdf'

c:\Users\ralf\Documents\document.pdf
```

Is the expectation here, that only drives that exist on the system may be used? I thought the whole point of  `join-path` and `split-path` was to work with arbitrary, non-existent paths... I remember reading this somewhere.

Comment: Currently (up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.4), `Join-Path` unfortunately requires that a given drive spec. refer to an _existing_ drive - [GitHub issue #4386](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4386) discusses this problematic behavior.
See the linked duplicate for workarounds.